# whats the diffrence between t=Turtle(shape="turtle") from code 1 and t.shape("turtle") from code 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Code 1

```
import random
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
t = Turtle()
screen=Screen()
screen.setup(width=900,height=500)
s=["fastest", "fast", "normal", "slow", "slowest"]
userbet=screen.textinput(title="make your bet",prompt="enter color")
color=["red","yellow","green","purple","orange"]
y=[-70,-40,-10,20,50]
for turtle_num in range(0,5):
    t=Turtle(shape="turtle")
    t.color(color[turtle_num])
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x=-230,y=y[turtle_num])
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image: output for code 1]

Code 2

```
import random
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
t = Turtle()
screen=Screen()
screen.setup(width=900,height=500)
s=["fastest", "fast", "normal", "slow", "slowest"]
userbet=screen.textinput(title="make your bet",prompt="enter color")
color=["red","yellow","green","purple","orange"]
y=[-70,-40,-10,20,50]
for turtle_num in range(0,6):
    t.shape("turtle")
    t.color(color[turtle_num])
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x=-230,y=y[turtle_num])
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image: output for code 2]

So i wanted to know why is code 2 producing only one turtle whereas code 1 is producing 5 turtle as of my knowledge **t=Turtle(shape="turtle")** from code 1 and **t.shape("turtle")** these two lines perform same task mostly i am wrong thats why there is diffrence i would be glad if someone can explain me diffrence.

Comment: did you miswrite and swap the images ?

Comment: First code instanciate a NEW turtle in each loop round, the second code deals with ONE turtle only

Comment: i guess yes i swaped image by mistake

Comment: why it deals with only one turtle still confused? @azro

Comment: Because you create only one, so there is no other, only `t = Turtle()` creates a turtle, if not you keep using the same one

Comment: so basically     `t.shape("turtle")` is creating one turtle right ?

Comment: did you not read my last comment ?  just said that ONLY `Turtle()` creates a turtle, the code you show only set the shape of the EXISTING turtle. You should read more python tutorial, you'd know that the code you show is only a method call, not an object creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is in the "mostly", the difference is huge:

The first code creates a new turtle at each iteration, setting a different color and a different destination `goto`

```
for turtle_num in range(0,5):
    t = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    t.goto(x=-230,y=y[turtle_num])
```

That means you do : turtle1 go there, turtle2 go there, turtle3 go there

---

The second code keeps moving the one and only one turtle instance, and changing it's color

```
t = Turtle()
for turtle_num in range(0,6):
    t.goto(x=-230,y=y[turtle_num])
```

That means : turtle go there, then go there, then go there